# How to split a list on an element delimiter

Tags: python, list, split

Are there concise and elegant ways of splitting a list in Python into a list of sub-lists by a delimiting element, such that `['a', 'delim', 'b']` -> `[['a'], ['b']]`?

Here is the example:

```
ldat = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b']
dlim = 'c'
lspl = []   # an elegant python one-liner wanted on this line!
print(lspl) # want: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

### Working examples that seem overly complex

I have surveyed documentation and related questions on stackoverflow - many referenced below - which did not answer my question, and am summarizing my research below: several approaches which *do* generate the desired output, but are verbose and intricate, and what is happening (splitting a list) is not immediately apparent -- you really have to squint.

Are there better ways? I am primarily interested in readability for beginners (e.g. teaching), canonical / 'Pythonic' approaches, and secondarily in the most efficient approaches (e.g. timeit speed). Ideally answers would address both Python 2.7 and 3.x.

#### with conditional .append()

Loop through the list and either append to the last output list or add a new output list. Based on an example that [includes the delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003351/7207622), but altered to exclude it. I'm not sure how to make it a one-liner, or if that is even desirable.

```
lspl = [[]]
for i in ldat:
    if i==dlim:
        lspl.append([])
    else:
        lspl[-1].append(i)
print(lspl) # prints: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

#### with itertools.groupby

Combine itertools.groupby with list comprehension. Many answers [include  delimeters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003860/7207622), this is based on those that [exclude delimeters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15358422/7207622).

```
import itertools
lspl = [list(y) for x, y in itertools.groupby(ldat, lambda z: z == dlim) if not x]
print(lspl) # prints: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

#### with slicing on indices

Some related questions have discussed how to use slicing after using .index() -- however answers usually focus on finding the [first index only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18571084/7207622). One can extend this approach by first [finding a list of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294205/7207622) and then looping through a self-zipped list to slice the ranges.

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(ldat) if x == dlim]
lspl = [ldat[s+1:e] for s, e in zip([-1] + indices, indices + [len(ldat)])]
print(lspl) # prints: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
```

However, like all the approaches I have found, this seems like a very complex way of enacting a simple split-on-delimiter operation.

### Comparison to string splitting

By comparison and as a model only, here is a working, concise, and elegant way of splitting
a string into a list of sub-strings by a delimiter.

```
sdat = 'abcabcab'
dlim = 'c'
sspl = sdat.split(dlim)
print(sspl) # prints: ['ab', 'ab', 'ab']
```

*NOTE: I understand there is no `split` method on lists in Python, and I am not asking about splitting a string. I am also not asking about splitting element-strings into new elements.*

Comment: The slicing on indices method is what comes to mind, although that is two lines. Wrap it in a function :) then it's one line

Comment: "I'm not sure how to make it a one-liner, or if that is even desirable." No, it isn't in and of itself. You can't get more canonical than a for-loop, really. In fact, the biggest problem I see with how you wrote your first example is by putting the `if` and `else` bodies on one line - use indentation.

Comment: Expected behavior if delimiter is at start or end?

Comment: Really any behavior is fine. So `['delim', 'a', 'b', 'delim']` could become `[['a'], ['b']]`, or `[[], ['a'], ['b'], []]`, or even `[['a'], ['b'], []]` or `[[], ['a'], ['b']]`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have indented the if/else example for legibility -- good point.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass right, that solution is *perfectly* Pythonic. It is very readable, the logic is straight-forward and expressed in typical python idioms, e.g. "append to the last sublist" => `lspl[-1].append(i)`. It is also *performant*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, I appreciate your point on its virtues. I am still hoping for even clearer alternatives. I am working on code for use by first-time programmers, and there is nothing *intuitive* about a conditional negative append = splitting.

Answer (score -4):

or this:

```
ldat = ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b']
dlim = 'c'
lspl = []   # an elegant python one-liner wanted on this line!
print(lspl) # want: [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]

s = str(ldat).replace(", '%s', " % dlim, "],[")
result = eval(s)
print(result)
```

Comment: Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: Wow. That does 'work' on that specific case, and it is simple, but it might be a bad combination of opaque and dangerous -- I really hope beginners won't cut-and-paste from this answer.