# sorting list into list of lists based on number

Tags: python, list

So, I was wondering how to sort this list:

```py
list = [
    '1',
    'China',
    'hello',
    '2',
    'India',
    '3',
    'America',
    'Texas',
    'Cowboy'
]
```

Into this new list of lists:

```py
newlist = [
    ['1', 'China', 'hello'], 
    ['2', 'India'], 
    ['3', 'America', 'Texas', 'Cowboy']
]
```

So I got the solution for my own problem, which is this code:

```py
list = [
    '1',
    'China',
    'hello',
    '2',
    'India',
    '3',
    'America',
    'Texas',
    'Cowboy'
]

newlist = []
a = 1
n = 0

for i in list:
    rltvList = list[n]
    
    if str(a) == rltvList:
        temporaryList = []
        a += 1
        newlist.append(temporaryList)
        
    temporaryList.append(rltvList)
    n += 1
```

Forgive my ugly coding, as I'm a beginner.

It's always good practice to write the pseudocode first before actually diving to the codes.

Here's my pseudocode logic for any of you wondering:

1. Go through `list` / loop through `list`;
2. If `list[x] = '1'` then append `list[x]` on to `temporaryList`;
3. Keep appending on to `temporaryList` until `list[x] = '2'`;
4. Append `temporaryList` on to `newList`;
5. Clear out `temporaryList`;
6. Do it over and over again until end of `list`.

We need `temporaryList` because we need to make `list` of lists. Without `temporaryList` it'll just be a list.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.  It's an important builtin name which is masked by the variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done:

```py
flat = ['1','China','hello','2','India','3','America','Texas','Cowboy']
target = []
n = 1
for i in flat:
    if i == str(n):
        target.append([i])
        n += 1
    else:
        target[-1].append(i)

print(target)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'China', 'hello'], ['2', 'India'], ['3', 'America', 'Texas', 'Cowboy']]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This code is already documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47662156/how-to-split-a-list-on-an-element-delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Update to the existing code because if the list starts with for example '5000' it won't work and send out an error message. So we gonna do a try & except.

Here's the new code:

```
list= ['4000','this','text','will','be','skipped','1','China','hello','2','India','3','America','Texas','Cowboy']
newlist=[]
a=1
n=0

for i in list:
    rltvList= list[n]
    
    if str(a) == rltvList:
        temporaryList=[]
        a+=1
        newlist.append(temporaryList)
    
    try:    
        temporaryList.append(rltvList)
    except Exception:
        pass
    
    n+=1

print(newlist)
```

It will output:

```
newlist=[['1', 'China', 'hello'],['2', 'India'],['3', 'America', 'Texas', 'Cowboy']]
```

Sorry for the bad code, I'm a beginner. Feel free to share some simpler, more elegant code.